# htaccess rewrite different directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are 4 rewrite rules, but only the first 2 work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^news/article/([^/]+)$ /path/to/news/?id=$1
RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]+)$ /path/to/news/?page=$1
RewriteRule ^company/careers/id/([^/]+)$ /path/to/company/careers.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^company/careers/page/([^/]+)$ /path/to/company/careers.php?page=$1
```

`/path/to` is always the same for all. The two `news` rules work perfectly, but the two `company` rules do not.

What's wrong here?

Edit to add (via comments):

This is how the 4 URLs look like.

`http://domain.com/folder/folder2/news/article/1`
=> translates correctly to `http://domain.com/folder/folder2/news/?id=1`

`http://domain.com/folder/folder2/news/page/2`
=> translates correctly to `http://domain.com/folder/folder2/news/?page=2`

`http://domain.com/folder/folder2/company/careers/id/1`
=> should translate to `http://domain.com/folder/folder2/company/careers.php?id=1`, but doesn't

`http://domain.com/folder/folder2/company/careers/page/2`
=> should translate to `http://domain.com/folder/folder2/company/careers.php?page=2`, but doesn't

The .htaccess file is located in `http://domain.com/folder/folder2/.htaccess`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42679/discussion-between-anubhava-and-bobsoap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your .htaccess to this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/folder2/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^news/article/([^/]+)/?$ news/?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]+)/?$ news/?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^company/careers/id/([^/]+)/?$ company/careers.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^company/careers/page/([^/]+)/?$ company/careers.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you - I've tried everything for mine to work with multiple folders without success until this solution.